# Storing and displaying multiple users' information with a text file

Tags: java, file, append, text-files

I am writing a program which allows the user to play a slot machine, then stores their name and score to a text file. At the beginning of the program and end of the slot machine game, there is a menu of three options a user can choose from:

1. To play a new game
2. View Scores
3. Exit the game.

When a user presses 2, the program should show the scores of each game, not just the game just played; so, whenever a user plays, their information should be appended to an already existing file, `score.txt`.

My problem is that whenever I try to read from this file, it only ever displays scores from the game just played. Here is the code that runs after the game ends:

```
System.out.println("Game over! Your score has been written to scores.txt" + name + "!"); 
System.out.print("Actions:\n");
System.out.println("1. Start a new game\n" + 
    "2. View scores\n" + 
    "3. Exit ");

System.out.println("Please select an action: ");
action = keyboard.nextInt();

while (action == 2) {
    File myFile = new File("score.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

    if (myFile.exists()) {
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            name = inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Name\n------\n" + name + "\n");
            total = inputFile.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("Scores\n------\n$%.2f\n", total);
            System.out.println();   
        }
    } else
        System.out.println("There are no scores to display at this time.");

    System.out.print("Actions:\n");
    System.out.println("1. Start a new game\n" + 
            "2. View scorse\n" + 
            "3. Exit ");

    System.out.println("Please select an action: ");
    action = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger or used println() to make sure your code does what you think it does?

Comment: And did you check your score.txt file? Does it really contain more than one highscore?

Comment: That's the problem. It doesn't contain more than one score. It should contain the score of every user who has ran the program and played the game but it is only storing scores of the user who just played. It is not appending the data of each player to the text file as I want it to and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You are showing the code for displaying the scores, If the scores aren't being saved correctly, you need to show us your saving code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a FileWriter make sure you pass true for the second argument to append.

```
try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("score.txt", true)));
    out.println(score);
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //deal with the exception
}
```